# Why changing the Z position of the 'camera' won't show the primitive?

Tags: c++, camera, directx, directx-9

I have an untransformed struct with the vertices coordination that'll form up a triangle:

```
struct utVertex ut_Vertex[] =
{
    { 2.5f, -3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), }, //a
    { 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), }, //b
    { -2.5f, -3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },//c
};
```

[image]

The image above *should* (not sure, because z axis could be inverted, + perhaps should be where - is) be correct according to my code:

```
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f),
        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    d3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);
```

The blue dot on the image above should be the camera position based on this code. (Please tell me if I'm wrong).

This draws a triangle correctly on screen.

[image]

Now, if I change the camera position to `-10.0f` instead of `10.0f` *(I think)* this is where the camera should be:

[image]

But it *should* still be looking at `0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f`. 
If it does, then why changing  Z position of the 'camera' won't show the primitive(triangle)?

Nothing shows:
[image]

Comment: I think because you try to render 3D withtout consideration of the 2D view transformation you need to calculate an orthonormal base to make a representation 2D "World2Screen".

Comment: I am doing the projection transformation

Comment: I guess you are on the transformation way but you need projection and translation if you want to animate it.

Comment: If you disable backface culling then it will be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygons you're using are single sided, so they are not visible when viewed from behind.  To get your triangle to show when you reverse the camera, you'll either need to add another polygon with the same points but listed in the opposite direction - (a,c,b) instead of (a,b,c) - or swap two of these points in your `ut_Vertex` array.

Comment: Or you could disable backface culling

Comment: can you explain *why* they are not visible when viewed from behind?

Comment: Oh nvm. `A triangle primitive is only drawn when its vertices are given in a clockwise order. If you flip it around, it becomes counter-clockwise, and is therefore not shown.`

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta That's the default behavior but you can change that behavior by changing render state